MERN stack cookies only working in the page which set the cookies
I am having trouble getting a cookie to operate across an entire website. I haven't worked in JS for a couple of years and cant seem to configure this properly.
I am working in a domain <client_name>.dev.domain, with a http server and the cookies are working properly for the page they are set on.
My code for setting cookies is the following:


app.use(cookie-parser("secret"));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!("cookie" in req.signedCookies) ||
      ("cookie" in req.signedCookies && req.signedCookies["cookie"] == undefined)) {
          console.log("cookie should be assigned");
          res.cookie(
            "cookie",
            "value",
            { 
              domain: '.dev.domain',
              maxAge: 3000,
              signed: true, 
              httpOnly: true,
              secure: false,
              sameSite: 'lax',
              path: '/',
            }
          );
  } else {
    console.log("cookie is already assigned");
  }
  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  cors({
    origin: ".dev.domain:3000",
    credentials: true
  })
  next();
});



Like I said this works for the home page where the cookies are initally set.
All subsequent fetches from the front end are using the fetch api and use the following function.


const getData = async (api_url, setData, setLoading) => {
  return await fetch(
    api_url,
    {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include",
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => setData(res))
    .then(res => setLoading(res))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error fetching data from: ");
      console.log(api_url);
      console.log(err);
    });
});



From everything I was reading, I figured it was an issue with the localhost domain name not meeting the subdomain.subdomain.domain requirements for I configured my /etc/hosts file to have 127.0.0.1 => <client_name>.dev.domain but this did not solve the issue.
I have tried specifying no domain name and that does not work.
I have tried using sameSite=None and that does not work.
The header for the setting of the cookie is
'set-cookie': 'cookie=; Max-Age=3; Domain=.dev.domain; Path=/; Expires=; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax;'
I have gone through a bunch of stackoverflow posts with similar problems but none of the solutions have helped.
Does anyone have any ideas on what I am misconfiguring that prevents this cookie from being used across multiple pages of the same website?
Thanks.

Have you tried calling cors directly? app.use(cors({...}))

@sori Yeah, I had it like that originally and just tried it again when called directly. No change in cookie behaviour.

ok forgive the naive question. Have you tried setting cors directly with the origin field set to match exactly with your frontend's origin? (including http:// or https://)

No worries. Any help is appreciated. I have tried that as well. The CORS does not give any warnings in the browser console. It seems happy. I think it is a domain problem because the session id cookie works website wide.

Have you checked the Domain attribute of your session ID cookie in the Application (Chrome) (or Storage (Firefox) tab)? Are there any differences with your custom cookie?

Same domain. Both use .dev.domain . Path=/ should allow the custom cookie to be used across the whole domain but doesnt seem to be working as I expected.

Setting credentials: 'include also requires sending Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers in the response. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RequestInit#credentials

Also, some nice suggestions here in case you haven't already had a look at it.

I have both Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and Access-Control-Allow-Origin set and get no CORS header warnings in the browser console.

I have gone through that thread before but it doesn't provide the solution I need. I already have credentials included in all my fetch calls and am not using localhost as my domain.

You say the Set-Cookie header contained Max-Age=3; - but that would only be three seconds. And doesn't appear to match the code you have shown; so can we assume that this was actually 3000, like it should be?
